# Dispose TCP port in .NET Remoting

Tags: c#, tcp, port, .net-remoting, tcpchannel

How can I truly dispose/release the TCP Channel(port) in code without application exit in my .NET remoting application?

The full code can be found on [GitHub](https://github.com/JerryBian/net-remoting).

#### Server

```cs
private static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Server side ....");

    while (true)
    {
        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Press S for stopping service, others for start ...");
        var key = Console.ReadKey();
        if (key.Key == ConsoleKey.S)
        {
            var channel = ChannelServices.GetChannel("x");
            ChannelServices.UnregisterChannel(channel);

            Console.WriteLine("TCP Channel stopped!!!");
        }
        else
        {
            var provider = new BinaryServerFormatterSinkProvider
            {
                TypeFilterLevel = TypeFilterLevel.Full
            };
            var props = new Hashtable
            {
                {"port", 25253},
                {"name", "x"}
            };
            var channel = new TcpServerChannel(props, provider);
            ChannelServices.RegisterChannel(channel, false);
            RemotingConfiguration.RegisterWellKnownServiceType(typeof(People), "p",
                WellKnownObjectMode.Singleton);

            Console.WriteLine("TCP Channel started!!!");
        }
    }
}
```

#### Client

```cs
private static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Client side ....");

    var i = 0;
    while (true)
    {
        try
        {
            var p = (People) Activator.GetObject(typeof(People), "tcp://localhost:25253/p");
            p.SetAge(i);
            Console.WriteLine($"{i} succeed => {p.Age}");
            Thread.Sleep(2000);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"{i} failed ==> {ex.Message}");
        }

        i++;
    }
}
```

Besides that, I use following PS command to check port usage:

```
 Get-Process -Id (Get-NetTCPConnection -LocalPort 25253).OwningProcess
```

While the channel was unregistered in Server, the port are still used by Server process.

Note: I am aware of another issue that even channel was unregistered, the client can still connect and operate successfully. There are some cache there, but anyway this is not an issue. What I want is the Port can be released without application terminated.